# Postfix don't send mail to external domain

Tags: email, internet, domain, postfix, external

Hi my postfix server can send and receive mail only from my local domain.

```
    root@vps-9c0d7878:/# root@vps-9c0d7878:/# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
compatibility_level = 2
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination =
myhostname = vps-9c0d7878.vps.ovh.net
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_proxy_options = speed_adjust
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.2m-partners.tn/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.2m-partners.tn/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

systemctl status amavis: (my domain => outlook)

> Jun 03 15:23:33 vps-9c0d7878 amavis[13844]: (1384 4-05) Passed CLEAN
> {RelayedInbound}, [196.178.210.179]:61879 [196.178.210 .179]
> imen@2m-partners.tn -> admin@2m-partners.tn,<rayen_ben_said@out
> look.fr>, Queue-ID: 1A6532B994C, Message-ID:
> <1793227b-51b8-f199-b23e-9af a777afe9d@2m-partners.tn>, mail_id:
> SlXOR3r9sqvh, Hits: -0.999, size: 810 , queued_as: 3A6D22B994E, 5911
> ms

i don't have /var/log/mail.log for log

Can someone help me ?

Comment: What's happening when you try? Any bounce messages? Error messages? Syslog messages? Anything at all?

Comment: no error message

Comment: in systemct status amavis i get passed clean